# ListBox Control ListItem options as CheckBoxes in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, listbox, listitem

I have a long list of Categories in the database and I want to populate the categories in ASP.NET ListBox control instead of CheckBoxList control to save my web page space. But I want to make ListItem of the ListBox as check box so that user can select multiple categories. Currently I am selecting multiple values by pressing **Ctrl and Click** in each item. I believe if I can provide check box to select ListItem it would be more user friendly as well. Is there any possibility?

Comment: Is this ASP.Net Web Form or ASP.Net MVC?

Answer (score 0):

A way you can do this is start to add a boolean to the Model you are working with like:

```
    public class Category
    {
    public int CategoryId{ get; set; }
    public string CategoryName{ get; set; }
    public bool selected{ get; set; } //<- we can use this for checkboxes
    }
```

Create a list of your categories and something like this to your .cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <div style="height:490px; overflow:auto;">
            <br />
            <br />
            <table class="table dim-table">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Categories[i].CategoryId)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Categories[i].CategoryName)
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Categories[i].selected, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create and continue" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>






}
```

css:

```
.dim-table{
    background-color: #fff;
}

.dim-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #d8f0ff;

}
.dim-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Then now you can get the categories that have the boolean set to 'true'.

Hope this messy comment makes sense.

Comment: I can't use ASP.NET MVC. My code is in ASP.NET and using ListBox control for that.